# Why is a specific Swift class not visible to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

All

**Xcode 10.3 and Swift 5.0**

I have a complex project with 3 targets ("Name", "Name Test" and "Name Local")

I have set all interoperability headers between Swift and Objective-C, including the `Name-Bridging-Header.h`, the Objc Preprocessor Macros to import the `Name-Swift.h`, `Name_Test-Swift.h` or `Name_Local-Swift.h` selectively

```
#ifdef TEST
#import "Name_Test-Swift.h"
#elif LOCAL
#import "Name_Local-Swift.h"
#else
#import "Name-Swift.h"
#endif
```

I have imported several Swift classes that I use frequently and everything works fine.

Now....

I added a new Swift class. This new class is subclass of NSObject

```
class NewClass: UIView { }
```

But using the new class in a `Objective-C` class, Xcode can't find this new class, with these errors:

`# import "Name-Swift.h"` is not recognized.

`NewClass *item = [NewClass alloc];`  - Unknown type name 'NewClass'

I checked the following:
- The new class is added to all Targets and is verified in the **Build-Phases**->**Compile-Sources** section

- My other Swift classes don't have public or @objc identifiers, and everything works OK.....   So I still I tried using them in the new class (@objc and public in the class definition), with no success

With only adding `NewClass *item = [NewClass alloc];` in any Objective-C class makes Xcode to stop recognizing `"Name-Swift.h"`

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you performed the usual rituals of Product>Clean, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode?

Comment: Hi @Yonat...  I tried all that, and also rebooting my Mac and restarting Xcode....   What I found is that I can't declare a Swift class instance in the .h file and I have to do it in the .m

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I found that I need to import the `Name-Swift.h` file in the .h file where I want to declare my object.

My project defines the `#import Name-Swift.h` in the `Name-Prefix.pch`

```
#ifdef TEST
#import "Name_Test-Swift.h"
#elif LOCAL
#import "Name_Local-Swift.h"
#else
#import "Name-Swift.h"
#endif
```

The #import declaration in the .pch file allows the Swift class to be accesible anywhere from the .m file of my Objective-C class, but not from the .h

I am not sure if that is the expected behavior... I will do a deep dive to the Documentation.

Comment: “What I found is that I can't declare a Swift class instance in the .h file” What would that even mean? You should not be declaring any Swift class in a .h file and you should not be importing the generated Swift header there. If you need to mention a Swift class in a .h file, just forward declare the name with `@class`.